# List files inline in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm scripting a .bat file that opens txt files after what user selects.

Bat file

```
@echo off

color 0a

:START

dir /b C:\pwd

set /p password= What are you looking for?

dir /b C:\pwd\%password%

set /p folder= What file?

type C:\pwd\%password%\%folder%.txt 

echo.

GOTO NEXT

:NEXT

set /p exit= Something else? (Y/N)

if %exit% == Y ( GOTO START )
```

But the `dir /b` shows the folders/text file on a newline, but can i show the files inline, almost like this

| File-one.txt | File-two.txt | File-three.txt |

i know just the `dir` command but i dont want the 1 files 0bytes thingie etc.

Comment: Why not just use the /D or /W options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for %%f in ("*") do ...` to match specific files, and then use `set /p _OUTPUT=%*<nul` as an echo command without a line feed. So, this should work as you requested...

```
@echo off
color 0a
:START
set /p _OUTPUT=^| <nul
for %%f in ("C:\pwd\*") do set /p _OUTPUT=%%f ^| <nul
set /p password= What are you looking for?
set /p _OUTPUT=^| <nul
for %%f in ("C:\pwd\%password%\*") do set /p _OUTPUT=%%f ^| <nul
set /p folder= What file?
type C:\pwd\%password%\%folder%.txt 
echo.
GOTO NEXT
:NEXT
set /p exit= Something else? (Y/N)
if %exit% == Y ( GOTO START )
```

Comment: I just added a minor change to output the filenames as you described `| File1 | File2 | ... | `.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to build a List.

Something like this should help :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 0a
set "reset=set $l="

:START

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-a "C:\pwd"') do set "$l=!$l! ^| %%a"
echo !$l!
%reset%
set /p "password= Name of the directory you want to look IN ? : "

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "C:\pwd\%password%\*.txt"') do set "$l=!$l! ^| %%a"
echo !$l!
%reset%
set /p folder= What file?

2>nul type "C:\pwd\%password%\%folder%.txt" || echo File not found

echo.

GOTO NEXT

:NEXT

set /p exit= Something else? (Y/N)

if %exit% == Y ( GOTO START )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /d /a-d "C:\pwd\%password%" | findstr /v "Bytes :"
```

`dir /d` takes care of proper formatting (depending on lenght of the longest filename, number of columns to fit to Screen, no line-wrapping within a filename).

remove `/a-d` if you want to show folders too.

You can also use `/w` instead of `/d`. The difference is horizontal vs. vertical sorting.

By default, sorting is with filenames, but you can change it with `/oX`